# C# - how to make a screenshot of DirectX application

Tags: c#, graphics, directx, screenshot

I have a C# WinForms app which takes a screenshot of selected process in windows. It utilizes a Graphics class, namely Graphics.CopyFromScreen. The problem is that for some DirectX applications and games it returns a black screen.

I don't know much about graphics nor DirectX, from what read upon I understand the Graphics class is a wrapper for Windows’s GDI+ interface having some buffer to which the DirectX is pumping content which could be programmatically changed (and different to what's actually displayed on the monitor) to a black screen when the screenshot action is detected.

I'm not very sure if this is exactly how it works or how to solve that. Does anyone know more about this? How to successfully take a screenshot in such use case?

I read that it's possible to somehow hook to DirectX’s output, but that apps can be monitoring such actions and preventing it.
I'm out of my depth here, could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: GDI/GDI+ and DirectX are quite different technologies (although they can interoperate). Sarting with Windows 10, you can capture the screen with WinRT's `Windows.Graphics.Capture` namespace classes, which you can use from .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

Comment: @SimonMourier I think that works only in UWP, not in win forms.

Comment: Not at all, doc's title is misleading, the API is WinRT. This works with regular Win32 apps, and any language that has binding for WinRT (C#, .NET, C++, etc.)